# gammu not saving sent messages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sms, gammu

I just got install gammu and the documentation is 40% helpfull. I would like to ask why gammu failed to save sent sms.

```
[gammu]
Device = /dev/ttyUSB0
Connection = at
InboxPath = /home/xxx/.config/gammu/inbox
OutboxPath = /home/xxx/.config/gammu/outbox
SentSMSPath = /home/xxx/.config/gammu/sent
ErrorSMSPath = /home/xxx/.config/gammu/error
InboxFormat = details
Service = FILES
```

I created a config file in /home/xxx/.config/gammu/config

I send a example command using this

```
gammu sendsms TEXT MyPhonenumberHere -text "Hello Gammu."
```

It was successful, I was able to get the message yet I can't find the sent sms into the path I configured. The message should be in the sent folder located at the

```
/home/xxx/.config/gammu/sent
```

The documentation is difficult to understand because of limited examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two things in Gammu:

- [Gammu utility](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/)
- [Gammu SMS daemon](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/)

The configuration you're mentioning belongs to the SMS daemon (and the configurations belong to the [[smsd] section](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html)), while you're invoking the Gammu utility directly.

So either send messages directly as you're doing and handle the logging yourself or execute the daemon and send the messages through [gammu-smsd-inject](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/inject.html).